# How to read values containing symbols ( for ex: [1,2,3] as list or 1D/2D array) from excel file and assign to a variable in python?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, csv, openpyxl

Excel file name= abc, sheet name= sheet1 and in cell A12= [1,2,3] and in B34 =[[1,3,4],[0,3,1]]
And
Now I need to assign a=[1,2,3] and b=[[1,3,4],[0,3,1]] in python

I have tried openpyxl but it returns None.

```
import openpyxl

theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('abc.xlsx')
csheet = theFile['sheet1']
a=csheet['A12'].value
b=csheet['B34'].value
print(a,b)
.
# The above code returns 
# None
# None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i succesfully run python script in folder with excel file

```
import openpyxl

theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('abc.xlsx')
csheet = theFile['sheet1']
a = ''.join(csheet['A12'].value)
b=''.join(csheet['B34'].value)
print(a,b)
print(type(a))
print(type(b))
```

screenshot of result
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEpZF.png

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can check your excel file path in system was wrong.
Try using Absolute path:

```
openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/users/xxx/Desktop/abc.xlsx')
```